# Get all values from a list of list with jq

Tags: json, jq

I would like to get all `topics` in this `json`:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/exercism/c/master/config.json
$ cat config.json | jq merge(.[].topics)
```

But obviously the above code does not work...

At the end I would like a list of all the topics:

```
arrays
control_flow_loops
...
```

I am more familiar with regexp and one solution not involving `jq` could be:

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $_ =~ s/[ ",]//gr for 
    m/topics.*?\[\K.*?(?=\])/smg' config.json | sort -u
```

**Example**

With this input:

```
{
    "exercises": [
        {
            "topics": [
                "foo"
            ]
        },
        {

            "topics": [
                "bar",
                "baz"
            ]
        },
        {
            "topics": [
                "foo",
                "qux"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like this output:

```
foo
bar
baz
qux
```

Comment: Post input/output examples.

Comment: @oguzismail You have both. You have a working exemple with the `perl` one liner.

Comment: nope, I won't connect to a server belongs to a notorious company and download probably malicious content, and I won't install a write-only language's bloated interpreter. See [mcve]

Comment: @oguzismail Well, I have added an example

Comment: @Dmitry - It might be more helpful if you could add a separate answer with a brief explanation of your solution ... for those who do not know jtc, the learning curve might be quite steep.

Comment: @peak, thanks, but when I add it as a standalone answer to questions which  marked explicitly with `jq`, my answers gets often downvoted

Comment: @Dmitry - Understood. There are some meanies out there. Still, if you are going to add a jtc solution in a comment, a small hint would be helpful.

Comment: @oguzismail, do you think providing an _alternative but correct_ solution ever qualifies as a spam (especially given the software is given for free entirely)?  - that's the notion I got reading that post on meta. (otherwise I don't get the relevance to my case)

Comment: @Dmitry nah, I don't think that it's spam. But it gets irritating when you keep doing that to promote your product (free/nonfree, doesn't matter). Btw, I never downvoted your answers, but I'm almost a hundred sure that question was about you, so I linked it so you can see it too if you didn't before

Comment: @Dmitry It qualifies as spam if you don't disclose your affiliation to the tool. Just your comment alone here meets exactly the criterion of being about your own tool without you disclosing that it's yours.

Comment: @oguzismail, thanks Oguz for pointing out the link, it does sound pretty much like about me. But it's just one side of the story and not entirely correct one. I wondering if I should respond on meta, or just suck it up, shut up and sit quiet. After reading that post on meta, I'm not even sure now that I'm doing a right thing by showing an alternative approach to JSON questions - it's a catch 22: besides me there is no one who can show that alternative approach. But it turns out if I do, it's spammy and self-promotional... and it does sound like sharing alternatives is a bad thing now.

Comment: @Dmitry I'm not the person to tell you what to do. But I'd respond to that post or create another post on meta asking *How do I go about promoting my own tool without spamming questions?* on such a situtation. I wouldn't keep silent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
< config.json jq '.. | objects | .topics[]?'
```

If you want to remove duplicates, you could pipe the above into `sort -u`, or use jq to do the same, e.g. using `unique`.

### Without ..

In some contexts, `..` may be inappropriate, so here is a `..`-free solution to the problem at hand:

```
< config.json jq '[.[][]?.topics[]?] | unique[]'
```

Comment: This is the `..` that I was missing :)